# How can i resolve this MarkerCluster checkin/ checkout error (leaflet salesforce)?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, salesforce, salesforce-lightning, leaflet.markercluster

The problem is that when i check out  on overlay and after i check in again  i receive this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined throws at
>   dist/leaflet.markercluster.js:1:25696 TypeError: Cannot read  property
>   'x' of undefined    at L.DistanceGrid._sqDist (DistanceGrid.js:114)
>   at L.DistanceGrid.getNearObject (DistanceGrid.js:94)    at e._addLayer
>   (MarkerClusterGroup.js:974)    at eval (MarkerClusterGroup.js:249)
>   at e.addLayers (MarkerClusterGroup.js:283)    at e.addLayers
>   (layersupport.js:99)    at e.onAdd (layersupport.js:517)    at
>   e._layerAdd (leaflet.js:5)    at e.whenReady (leaflet.js:5)    at
>   e.addLayer (leaflet.js:5)

```
I saw that this function from DistanceGrid(is in leaflet library) which is called when i check in on the overlay 

_sqDist: function (p, p2) {
      var dx = p2.x - p.x,
          dy = p2.y - p.y;
      return dx * dx + dy * dy;
  }
```

And when i checked in is p  is somehow undefined. Im struggling with this error for a long period already. Maybe you have some suggestion

Markers are defined for the groups and they are properly displayed the issue is only with check in check out. Once i check them out the clusters dissapear as they should and once i checked in i receive  that error mentioned before instead of showing clusters back on the map

Here is the controller code:

```
JS controller: 
var map = L.map('map', {zoomControl: true, tap: false, preferCanvas:true})
var group1,group2,group3,group4;
var myRenderer = L.canvas({ padding: 0.5 });
 var markers = L.markerClusterGroup.layerSupport( { 
        chunkedLoading: true,
        renderer: myRenderer,
        iconCreateFunction: function  (cluster) {
        var childCount = cluster.getChildCount();

        var c = ' marker-cluster-';
        if (childCount < 10) {
            c += 'small';
        } 
        else if (childCount < 100) {
            c += 'medium';
        } 
        else {
                c += 'large';
        }

        return new L.DivIcon({ html: '<div><span>' + childCount + '</span> 
</div>', 
                              className: 'marker-cluster' + c, iconSize: 
 new L.Point(40, 40) });
            }
});

 group1 = L.layerGroup(),
       group2 = L.layerGroup(),
      group3 = L.layerGroup(),
       group4 = L.layerGroup(),

    markers.checkIn([group1, group2, group3, group4]);

    var overlayMaps = {
        "g1": group1,
        "g2": group2,
        "g3":group3,
        "g4":group4
    };
    var control = L.control.layers(null, overlayMaps, { collapsed: true });


    control.addTo(map);

    group1.addTo(map); // Adding to map or to AutoMCG are now equivalent.
    group2.addTo(map);
    group3.addTo(map);
    group4.addTo(map);

 markers.addTo(map);
```

PS: I dont know how to give a workable version since this a salesforce app

Comment: Please provide a runnable [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that the `chunkedLoading` option is not well handled by the Leaflet.markercluster.layerSupport plugin.

I am not sure why you need to "checkout" and "checkin" regularly? Are you rather referring to using the Layers Control to remove / add your overlay?

Otherwise, if you "only" need a solution to use Leaflet.markercluster with the Layers Control, you can give a try to the simpler plugin [Leaflet.FeatureGroup.SubGroup](https://github.com/ghybs/Leaflet.FeatureGroup.SubGroup), although if `chunkedLoading` is the reason for the issue, it would probably also be the same with that plugin.

Comment: I solved that with subgroup. One thing that i realised using that is, if you  create a new subgroup  you always need to specify the array of markers at the creation  otherwise when you check out at the check in nothing will be displayed                 
EX: var group1 = L.featureGroup.subGroup(parent,group1Array); . Also no need for layout support in this case. And yes im removing and adding the layers @ghybs. Thank you everyone for helping me make the information clear and  give me a good solution

Answer (score 1):

I resolve the issue by adding all the vertices together, I created an array that contains all the vertices and then added them using the function addLayers

```
  const folders = 800;
  for (let index = 0; index < folders; index++) {
    const folder = this.createFolder();
    this.folders.push(folder);
  }
  this.clustersFeature.addLayers(this.folders);
```